# Advance Conditions for Pricing for shipping

Tags: cart, shipping

Hello 
How i can make next for pricing for shipping:

1. Manufacturer - items (from different manufacturers different
   delivery charges)
2. Free Shipping:

   - On some items
   - Some manufacturers are always free
   - When the amount in the cart reaches a certain value, $ 1000 or more

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution would be the following :

1) Use an exentension to give a price to all products. Free extension here : http://www.webshopapps.com/eu/free/product-flat-rate-shipping-extension.html

2) Free shipping.

Use the shopping cart promo rules, to set free shipping when the rules are matched.

Comment: you can tell what about shopping cart promo rules, to set free shipping when the rules are matched if possible let me details